# Declaring a retrofit REST endpoint with constant query value

Tags: java, retrofit

So I want to get the metadata of a youtube video (say this one: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qlTA3rnpgzU`).

I'm going to encode it and wrap it in another url like so: `http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DqlTA3rnpgzU&format=json`

My interface definition will look like this:

```
public interface YoutubeApi {
    @GET ("oembed") 
    YoutubeMetaData metaData (@Query (QUERY_VIDEO_URL) final String url,
                              @Query(QUERY_FORMAT) final String alwaysJson);
}
```

That's all fine and dandy, but I don't ever want to specify any format other than JSON here (*format=json is a fixed part of this url*).

Is there a way to specify this in my interface declaration and reduce my interface to:

```
public interface YoutubeApi {
    @GET ("oembed") 
    @Magic ("format=json")
    YoutubeMetaData metaData (@Query (QUERY_VIDEO_URL) final String url);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Just put it right in the relative URL:

```
public interface YoutubeApi {
  @GET("oembed?format=json") 
  YoutubeMetaData metaData(@Query(QUERY_VIDEO_URL) String url);
}
```

Comment: In Retrofit 1, we can use @QueryParam annotation

@GET("endpoint")
@QueryParam(name="constantVariable", value="constantValue")
void normalGet(@Named("page") int page, Callback<MyResponse> callback);
Reference: JakeWharton's comment https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/103#issuecomment-10738504

Comment: @nizam.sp This is still simpler.

Answer (score 4):

In kotlin you can specify the default parameter:

```
interface YoutubeApi {

    @GET ("oembed") 
    suspend fun metaData (
        @Query (QUERY_VIDEO_URL) url: String,
        @Query(QUERY_FORMAT) alwaysJson: String = "json"
    ): Response<YoutubeMetaData>

}
```